# Swift NSNumberFormatter

Tags: swift, function, xcode6, nsnumberformatter

I am working through my swift book and building as I go. I am having trouble with this NSNumberFormatter class. I keep getting the error:
 "Expected Declaration"
after my statement of

```
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
```

I have re written my code multiple times and I have compared every letter to my book and I don't understand where I have gone wrong

And when I try to run the function with:

```
account1.deposit(depositAmount)
```

I get the error message again of "Expected Declaration

Here is my code:

```
    //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

    import Cocoa
    import Foundation

    public class Account
    {
    public var name: String = ""
    public var balance: Double = 0.0


    public init(name: String, balance: Double)
    {
        self.name = name
        if balance > 0.0
        {
            self.balance = balance
        }
    }

    public func deposit(amount: Double)
    {
        if amount > 0.0
        {
            balance = balance + amount
        }
    }

    public func withdraw(amount: Double)
    {
        if balance - amount >= 0.0
        {
            balance = balance - amount
        }
    }



   let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
  formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle


    func formatAccountString(account: Account) -> String {
        return account.name + "'s balance: " + formatter.stringFromNumber(account.balance)!
    }




    let account1 = Account(name: "Jane Green", balance: 50.00)
    let account2 = Account(name: "John Blue", balance: -7.53)

   //println(formatAccountString(account1))

    var depositAmount = 25.53
    account1.deposit(depositAmount)
    account2.deposit(depositAmount)

    println("depositing " + formatter.StringFromNumber(depositAmount) + " into account1\n")
    println("depositing " + formatter.StringFromNumber(depositAmount) + " into account1\n")
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in location of the `formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle`. You can't run code from the class level. Move it to the init.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Took me embarrassingly long to figure this out even when I had it in a playground :|

Comment: Thanks, I just moved it to the constructor but after my 

    account1.deposit(depositAmount)

statement, I still get the same error message of "Expected Declaration".

Comment: It's the same problem.

Comment: Yes. And when you fix that, you will have problem with account2 and with the prints. You can't execute code from the class/struct body. You need to move it to a function like you did with the formatter.